# Prove an equation using the law of total expectation

Tags: probability, optimization, proof-explanation, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> Question: Given a fair coin, there are $4$ possible outcomes if we toss the coins twice, they are $HH, HT, TH, TT.$
>   If we obtained one of $HH,HT,TH,$ then we stop tossing. If we obtained $TT,$ we continue tossing. 
>   Find the expected number of tosses to stop tossing the fair coin.

Answer: Let $N$ be the number of tosses required to stop tossing. **Then we have 
$$E[N] = \frac{3}{4}\times 2 + \frac{1}{4}(2 + E[N]).$$**
Solving the equation above leads to 
$$E[N] = \frac{8}{3}.$$

I understand that $$E[N] = \frac{3}{4}\times 2 + \frac{1}{4}(2 + E[N])$$ is due to the law of total expectation. But I would like to prove the equation above using the law.
But to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not content with your solution ? Do you want an explicite formula ?

Comment: @Peter I am contented with the solution. However, I feel like I do not really understand it mathematically. I understand intuitively on how to obtain $E[N] = \frac{3}{4}\times 2 + \frac{1}{4}(2 + E[N]).$ But in this post, I would like to prove it using the law of total expectation, but unable to do so.

Comment: The only interesting case is that we start with $TT$ , then the first $H$ leads to a halt. Did you try to exploit this ?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate more? I do not quite understand your comment

Comment: What I mean is that the expected number of tosses is simply $4$, if we start with $TT$ (the two tosses $T$ and the expected number we need to get $H$). Or did I misunderstand the question ?

Comment: Yes, I understand that the expected number of tosses is $4$ by the mean formula of geometric distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$p(2m+2) = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^m \frac{3}{4}$, for $m \geq 0$.

So $\operatorname{E}(N) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (2i+2) \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^m \frac{3}{4}$

Now, see that  $\left( \operatorname{E}(N) - 2 \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) \right) \times 4 = \operatorname{E}(N) + \operatorname{E}(2)$.

Your distribution is geometric, so you are just solving for the expected value of a geometric random variable.